# Opposing effects in LME4 formulae (Bradley-Terry model)

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, binary-data, bradley-terry-model

Suppose I'm modelling a two-player game, and I want to estimate the probability $p$ of the first player winning, given the players involved. I want to do this using the formula $$p_{ij} = \textrm{logit}(s_i - s_j) + \epsilon,$$ where $s_k$ is the skill level of the $k^{th}$ player, and game is between player $i$ and player $j$.

If I use a data frame, with a binary column `P1win` for player 1 winning a game, a column $s_1$ for the first player, and a column $s_2$ for the second player, and use the formula $$\textrm{P1win} \sim s1 + s2$$ in `glm` with a logit link, this effectively can assign players different skill levels for going first and going second, when I want their skill level to be independent of turn order.

How would I set this formula up in `lme4`?

EDIT: I could just make a design matrix, where player 1 gets the value $1$, and player 2 gets the value $-1$. However, unless I'm missing a trick, this would require having a separate column for each player, and plugging each player column's name into the formula. I'm working with an arbitrary (and increasing) number of players, so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do it in `lme4`? 
`R` has a package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/) to do Bradley-Terry models.

Comment: Because I'm using it as part of a bigger model, and I want Monte Carlo samples. My broader goal is to learn how to use `lme4` formulae work, so that I can use `rstanarm` instead of `rstan`, and use the `loo` package for cross-validation.

Comment: Reading up on the `loo` package a bit more, it also works with normal `rstan` models, so my reason for asking this question is moot. I'm keeping the question up, because this seems like something people might want to do in `lme4`.

Comment: > I could just make a design matrix, where player 1 gets the value 1, and player 2 gets the value −1. how is this done ? I don't see how to specify an arbitrary random effects design matrix in `lme4`. thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The Bradley-Terry model you describe is just a special case of a multiple membership model, which `lme4` unfortunately does not have built-in support for. However, `lmerMultiMember` was developed for exactly this purpose; specifying models with arbitrary random effects matrices and passing these off to `lme4` for model fitting.

I wrote a [vignette](https://jvparidon.github.io/lmerMultiMember/articles/bradleyterry_models.html) explaining how to fit Bradley-Terry models using `lmerMultiMember`.